# android studio: how to change from junit 3 to junit 4

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, junit

My android studio is running JUnit 3. How do I change it to JUnit 4?
I believe my gradle file is correct.

```
android {
  …
  defaultConfig {
    …
    testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  …
}

dependencies {
    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    // Optional -- Hamcrest library
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    // Optional -- UI testing with Espresso
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    // Optional -- UI testing with UI Automator
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
}
```

I am using the Android Studio `2.1.1`

**update**

Actually it turns out I am using JUnit 4 but for whatever reason I have to prefix my test cases with `test` as in `testSomeMethodForX` as opposed to simply `someMethodForX`. I thought in JUnit 4, this prefixing was no longer necessary?

Comment: Can you share your test code?

Answer (score 1):

If your classes still extend `TestCase` (or another class that itself extends `TestCase`) then JUnit 4 runs them a JUnit 3 tests and therefore you have to prefix them with `test`. Don't extend `TestCase` anymore and they are run if the `@Test` annotation is present.

Comment: My class does NOT extend `TestCase`